# Adding and removing classes in specific div with the change of slides in carousel in jquery/ js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I am using slick slider and i want to add/remove "active" in a div which is outside  (somewhere else in the page) slick slider code. For example: I have this code for the slider.

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="showcase-1"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="showcase-2"><img src="img/2.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="showcase-3"><img src="img/3.jpg" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

Now on change of slide, "active" class should be added to div and then the "active" class should be removed by itself when the slide is changed and it should be added to second div which is for second slide. Note that every div is for each slide. Like first div is for "showcase-1" slide and second div for "showcase-2".

```
<div class="showcase"></div>
<div class="showcase"></div>
<div class="showcase"></div>
```

I tried this jquery and it's working good but it's not changing the classes on change of slides.:D i am sure this is not a right way!

```
$(function() {
 if ($(".slider .showcase-1").hasClass("slick-current")) {
     $("div.showcase-1").addClass('active');
 } else {
     $('div.showcase-1').removeClass('active');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[It looks like Slick slider developers have already found and fixed this bug](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1248) where all slides were getting the "slick-active" class. Now all slides get slick-active but only the current slide gets "slick-slide slick-current slick-active" classes.

If you use the latest version of Slick you will receive this improvement and won't have to write your own.

[See the Slick slider demos here](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and inspect them and you will see these more helpful, updated classes.

Comment: I guess you didn't understood my question. Actually i want to add class to a div which is not linked with slick slider. When one slide is active, a class should be added to a div (any div in the page) and the class should be removed when the slide is changed.

Comment: are you adding thumbnails to your slider?

Comment: No. It's a simple slideshow. Above the slider, there are 3 div blocks. What i want is to link those blocks to the slides. The background color of a block should change with the change of slide. That's why i want to add and remove class in those blocks with the change of slides.

Comment: That's what slider thumbnails do. :) Found a couple variations: http://jsfiddle.net/Virtual/webyrb9d/ and https://jsfiddle.net/keithpetrillo/6j7fzwek/. Close to what you're looking for?

Comment: to be honest i didn't get it :D thumbnail means images. But i have text in those blocks and it's completely separate from the slider container.

Comment: Nope it's note!... Wait let me show you the website i am working on!

Comment: This is the website! http://zivit.theme-ace.com/

see "What is it?" section. There are 3 blocks "A SOCIAL NETWORK" "Game" and "Market place". Now what i want is that with the change of slide below, the background color of these block should change.

Comment: P.S The slider on the website is owl carousel but i am working with the Slick slider on the backend and didn't updated the website yet!

Comment: I understand what you mean now, but you really should update your question. I'll have a think of how to do it with Owl.

Comment: Thanks mate! Let's see how much more clear i can get :D i'll update the question then.